# Android studio not launching suddenly after restarting my MAC

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-bumblebee

[image]

Suddenly after restarting my Mac ,i ended up not able to open android studios ,just stuck at loading state as showing in image

Comment: I have removed and reinstall again but no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this problem I had to move (or delete) the AndroidStudio2021.1 folder from /Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google.

Now it starts again.

I suggest to move the folder instead of deleting it. Some settings must be restored from there

Comment: Much appreciated ,Issue resolved after spending whole day trying to resolve the issue but no luck .I did follow above steps and worked